# Rake db:migrate adds :precision option to datetime columns

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

Running rake db:migrate adds :precision options to all the datetime columns in my tables. I'm not making any new database migrations so I'm not sure where that is coming from.

I'm running

- psql (PostgreSQL) 9.6.11
- Ruby 2.3.1
- Rails 5.0.1

Changes happen in the schema.rb file. Not sure why it would add that precision option on my computer though. I'm running the same versions as the other developer.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide some more information about your question for the best possible chance for someone to help you. Useful information to include in questions an example of what you are trying to do, what you expect it to do and what it is doing instead. Error messages help a lot as well as being as descriptive as possible.

Comment: You may want to make sure that these versions are the same for every developer working on the project

Comment: Yes I'm seeing these changes in the scheme.rb file. Now that you mention that part about db:schema:dump. I did import a SQL file that built out my database tables instead of using rake:db:load because the other developer had a development database already made. Not sure if that would mess something up?

Comment: Yes we are working with the same versions.